# Axios `PUT` 500 Error when trying to add contract to sendgrid

Tags: axios, next.js, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I am trying to take user emails and put them into sendgrid as a contract list. It seems like some information is being lost when trying to add new emails to the list but am unsure exactly what is causing the problem.

First I have a hero component that contains the area of email collection:

```
const Hero = () => {

  const [mail, setMail] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  
  //Called onClick()
  const subscribe = () => {
    setLoading(true);
    axios.put("api/sendgrid/mailingList", mail)
      .then((result) => {
        if (result.status === 200) {
          toast.success(result.response.data);
          setLoading(false);
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.response.data);
        setLoading(false);
      });
  };
```

The axios put from the previous section goes to my api/sendgrid/mailingList:

```
import axios from "axios";
 
export default async function handler(req, res) {

 if (req.method === "PUT") {
   await axios.put("https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/marketing/contacts", {
         contacts: [{ email: req.body.mail }],
         list_ids: [process.env.SENDGRID_MAILING_ID],
       },
       {
         headers: {
           "content-type": "application/json",
           Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SENDGRID}`,
         },
       }
     )
     .then((res) => {
       res.status(200).send({
         message:
           "Your email has been succesfully added to the mailing list. Welcome ",
       });
     })
     .catch((error) => {
       res.status(500).send({
         message:
           "There was a problem with your subscription, please try again or contact us",
       });
     });
 }
}
```

I am able to access my API script but am met with the following error:

> PUT http://localhost:3000/api/sendgrid/mailingList 500 (Internal
> Server Error)

The network tab on the console tools:

[image]

Comment: Well, you are catching an error on the server side. Why not just check what the error is? It might give you some information about what went wrong

Comment: @derpirscher I updated the question with the console tools screen shot. Still not 100% sure what the issue is. The payload is returning an email address as it should. The only thing that looks like it may be off is the remote address: [::1]:3000

Comment: The relevant thing you should inspect is what the `error` in your `catch((error)` is. because that's telling you what's actually going wrong [::1] is just the IP6 version of 127.0.0.1

Comment: @JCDOSAJ You'll want to check the error on the server, i.e. on the terminal where you started your dev server. Make sure to call `console.log(error)` right before `res.status(500).send(...)`, that will tell you why the API route is erroring.